# Java RMI: How can I restrict RMI method to only be called internally by the client object

Tags: java, rmi, private, abstract, public

I have an RMI model which uses a thread on each side (Client/Server Side) to maintain a client heartbeat. If the client crashes without unlocking the server, the lock will eventually timeout.

I don't want the user of my client API to be able to call the methods that deal with the heartbeat/lock. However from my understanding of Java RMI, the client and server must implement a common interface which defines all the methods that I want RMI access to, and these methods must be public. Since the interface defines these methods as public, the client methods must also be public, and can not be hidden from the user.

**Question:**

Is there a way to restrict certain methods that have been exported over RMI so that only the client object itself can call them? In other words, can I make the method act as though it is private on the client side?

Comment: You don't need this. Have a look at the `Unreferenced` interface.

Comment: Thank you that is so much easier!

Comment: @EJP I actually don't think the Unreferenced interface will work for my situation. The unreferenced() method only gets called when ALL clients no longer reference the server. In my case, if the locked client session ends, there could still be other clients that have reference to the server (They just can't use it until they acquire a lock)

Comment: Then you need took at my Remote Session pattern. Several answers about it here.